# asterisk как отправить сообщение абоненту 100

Tags: asterisk

Запарился с простой, казалось бы, задачкой. Нужно, чтобы сам сервер отослал текстовое сообщение SIP-абоненту под условным номером 100. Пожалуйста, подскажите команду для extensions.conf, чтобы сообщение пошло от имени того, кто звонил на АТС извне или хотя бы с номером звонившего в тексте. Суть такая, типа "вам звонил такой-то"...